# Using tor over ssh on virtual network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtualbox, tor

I have two Machines running in VirtualBox, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with two network adapters (NAT,Internal Network) and Kali Linux with one adapter (Internal Network). I'm also running tor ( SocksPort 9150, ControlPort 9151 ) in Ubuntu. My goal is to have access on the internet from Kali only through tor. So I used ssh port forwarding from kali to ubuntu and also configured firefox to use proxy( 127.0.0.1 - 9150)

```
kali~# ssh -N -L 9150:10.0.3.2:9150 root@10.0.3.1
```

With this command i am trying to forward all the traffic into tor.

The connection is established according to netstat and ping is working but when i try to load a page nothing happens and i keep getting the same error message on Kali's terminal

```
channel 2: open failed : connect failed : connection refused
```

Am i missing something? Do i need to open a port?

I also tried to use a SOCKS proxy with

```
ssh -D 9150 root@10.0.3.1
```

but it didn't work. Please share your thoughts with me, I am waiting for your insights.Thank you.

**Internal Network Configuration:**

Ubuntu:

IP:10.0.3.1

Broadcast Address:10.0.3.255

Subnet Mask:255.255.255.0

Default Route:10.0.2.2

Primary DNS:192.168.1.1

Kali:

IP:10.0.3.2

Broadcast Address:10.0.3.255

Subnet Mask:255.255.255.0

**NAT Configuration:**

Ubuntu

IP:10.0.2.15

Broadcast Address:10.0.2.255

Subnet Mask:255.255.255.0

Default Route:10.0.2.2

Primary DNS:192.168.1.1

Comment: it is better if you setup Ubuntu machine(10.0.2.15) as default route for Kali and setup transparent proxy on Ubuntu for all trafic from 10.0.3.2

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will it be possible to route Kali's traffic through tor with the transparent proxy ?

Comment: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/IsolatingProxy https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/IsolatingProxy

Comment: The problem was with the ssh command kali~# ssh -N -L 9150:10.0.3.2:9150 root@10.0.3.1 , it worked with 127.0.0.1 instead of 10.0.3.2.